# Report Builder 3.0 - How to add 2 columns of values both belonging to the same field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, builder

Here is the view of table in ''conception'' view:
[Conception view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRgga.jpg)

And here's what it gives:
[Executed view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr9zT.jpg)

As you can see my Column group entitled `[Poste_Histo___Etat_Description_Abrégé]` breaks out into 3 categories when I run the report: `Comblé`, `Vacant` and `Vacant_att`

I want to blend `Vacant` and `Vacant att` into just 1 category and name it Vacant, so to have only 2 categories when the report is being run.

I tried multiple functions and there was one that got me close, but event then, it only renamed Vacant_att to Vacant and didn't add the 2 columns though:

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!Poste_Histo___Etat_Description_Abrégé.Value, "Vacant") Or InStr(Fields!Poste_Histo___Etat_Description_Abrégé.Value, "Vacant_att"), "Vacant", "Comblé")
```

So my goal is to figure this out and ultimately, portray these same values on a graph in the same manner: that is to have only "Vacant" and "Comblé" as categories.

p.s. If it makes any difference, all the «Expr» are the following formula:

```
=Sum(IIF(InStr(Fields!Poste.Value, ""+"300") Or InStr(Fields!Poste.Value, ""+"100"), 1, 0))
```

It's point is to only get the values for that end with 300 or 100.

Thanks a lot to any1 who helps!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding my answer myself lol. For any1 having eventually the same problem, here is my approach:

1- In the Query Designer pane of my dataset, I created 2 Calculated members: 
One being Comblé including the [Comblé] category and the other being Vacant in which I combined [Vacant] and [Vacant_att].

2- I used the formula mentioned in my question as partly successful and replaced the 1 with the newly created calculated members correspondingly. So:
For Vacant:
=Sum(IIF(InStr(Fields!Poste.Value, ""+"300") Or InStr(Fields!Poste.Value, ""+"100"), Fields!Vacant.Value, 0))
For Comblé:
=Sum(IIF(InStr(Fields!Poste.Value, ""+"300") Or InStr(Fields!Poste.Value, ""+"100"), Fields!Comblé.Value, 0))

3- So this gave me the right numbers BUT (as per the pic attached) as long as I had  [Poste_Histo___Etat_Description_Abrégé] as a Parent Group in my Tablix, which was no good since this dimension has 3 categories originaly (Vacant, Vacan att. and Comblé) I ended up with 3 columns who have 2 columns each (my newly created Calculated members - Vacant and Comblé)... so 6 columns 
[Table 1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wGSz.jpg)

4- Finally to tackle this issue, I created 2 columns both out of the parent group [Poste_Histo___Etat_Description_Abrégé] : Vacant2 and Comblé2. And I simply copy pasted that same formula in these but only to discover that the values were all 3 times larger (sum of the 3 columns). As a simple way out, I just divided each formula by 3 and . As so:
=(Sum(IIF(InStr(Fields!Poste.Value, ""+"300") Or InStr(Fields!Poste.Value, ""+"100"), Fields!Comblé.Value, 0)))/3

And voilà!

p.s. in Table 1.0, Vacant2 and Comblé2 are a percentage of the ratio of each calculated member over the sum of the two.